# Automate batch file transfer daily from Linux EC2 Instance to a Windows EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, file-transfer

I have 11 directories in Linux EC2 Instance where the external API adds data (.CSV files) to. I will need to schedule a job to copy ONLY those csv files from 11 directories  into matching directories inside the Windows EC2 Instance daily. Both the Instances are on the same VPC but on different Security groups. 
How can I accomplish the file transfer from Linux EC2 to a Windows EC2 in AWS?

Answer (score 0):

"Pushing" content to a computer is always difficult due to security. And, in this situation, it is also cross-platform.

A simple solution would be:

- Copy data from the source (Linux) computer to Amazon S3 on a regular schedule
- Copy data from Amazon S3 to the destination (Windows) computer on a regular schedule

This can be done by triggering a script from cron / Scheduled Task which runs the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws s3 sync` command. This is smart enough to copy files, but will only copy files that have been added/changed since the last use of the `sync` command.

See: [aws s3 sync — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)

You could copy the files hourly rather than daily, since there's no disadvantage.